# The problem with the publication of the bot

Tags: botframework

When you try to send a bot for review for publication in the browser console, you receive the following error:

[image: error]

what could be the reason?

The error text I see only in the console, the public part stops here forever [image]

as well as "publisher name" and "language" in the form of reset their values.

**P.S. Hmm, errors when posting to the browser console no longer seems to have corrected, thank you all for your help!**

Comment: Can you post the code of your skype-config.js?

Comment: No, I can't publish the code. This bot is used to connect in Open lines in the bitrix24 CRM system. It will be used to redirect messages from Skype to Open lines. More details can be found here https://helpdesk.bitrix24.com/open/8014709/?sphrase_id=33152045

Comment: Does the bot work locally?

Comment: At the moment the bot works perfectly. There's no problem with him. The problem is with the publication of this bot, because if it is not published, then only the first 100 users will be able to communicate with it. And we need to publish it to remove this restriction. And here to publish the bot still does not work because of the error which I mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm, errors when posting to the browser console no longer seems to have corrected, thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with bitrix, so I can't help you there, but more then likely the problem lies with how Skype is trying to "test" your bot. They have a rather rigorous process to approve bots, and one step is the bot must respond to a 'PING' event. The only problem with this is that PING was a v3 event, deprecated and removed from v4 altogether. You're going to have to write custom logic for how to respond if Skype sends a ping event. For example, here's how I wrote some a few months ago to handle this:

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (turnContext == null) { BOT CODE FOR ERRORS }
        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message) { BOT CODE FOR TALKING }  
        else if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate) { BOT CODE FOR WELCOME IN NON-SKYPE }
        else if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate) { BOT CODE FOR WELCOME IN SKYPE}

        //HERE'S WHERE IT WENT GOOGLY.
        else if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
        {
            if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "facebook")
            {
                //handle ALL OTHER channel specific events here
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{turnContext.Activity.Type} event detected", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                //handle skype with empty, because skype freaks out if you detect it's channel on the ping
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{turnContext.Activity.Type} event detected", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
```

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1074) is the Github issue that the above code comes from.

Comment: Hmm, errors when posting to the browser console no longer seems to have corrected, thank you all for your help!